# UIAppearance for UILabel in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uilabel, uialertcontroller, uiappearance

I have this code that changes the appearance of `UILabel`s when they appear in `UIAlertController`s:

```
UILabel *appearanceLabel = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIAlertController class]]];
    [appearanceLabel setAppearanceFont:kFontRegular(18)];
```

But this also affects the UILabels that appear in `UIActivityViewController`s.

[image]

How can I exclude the UILabels in `UIActivityViewController`?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to set / unset the appearance depending on your situation you may be able to subclass your own UIAlertController and use

```
UILabel *appearanceLabel = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[MyAlertController class]]];
    [appearanceLabel setAppearanceFont:kFontRegular(18)];
```

then when the action sheet opens it won't be your subclass so the rule won't apply.

Comment: this would probably work - but I have quite a large application that uses UIAlertController quite extensively.

Comment: It won't work as situation remains same as UIActivityViewController is using the same interface

Comment: techloverr I just tested the idea of using a subclass and it will only adjust the font for the subclass.  That would mean this would work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use class posing feature of `objective c` to use in as many as occurences of `UIAlertController`

[Class Posing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_posing.htm)